# Show only one result on foreach command (php)

Tags: php, file, foreach, directory

I've got the following code.

```
    if ($_GET['dir']!=''){
        $checkifhasfiles = array_diff(scandir($_GET['dir']), array(".","..","error_log"));
        foreach($checkifhasfiles as $cihf){
            if(is_file($_GET['dir'].'/'.$cihf)){
                echo "Ok, the folder has files";
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is only show `one` message if the folder contains `only` files. The problem is, as expected, the foreach is 'echoing' a message for each file the folder contains.

How can I 'bypass' that, and only print one message if the folder has files?

Thanks and best regards

BTW - Sorry for the indentation, I'm writing it on notepad, as I'm not at home, and it isn't perfectly indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with a "break" ? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
if ($_GET['dir']!=''){
     $checkifhasfiles = array_diff(scandir($_GET['dir']), array(".","..","error_log"));
     foreach($checkifhasfiles as $cihf){
         if(is_file($_GET['dir'].'/'.$cihf)){
            echo "Ok, the folder has files";break;
         } 
      }  
   }
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thank you so much. Didn't know about that! I'll accept your answer after the 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you don't simply want to echo out on the first found file, but if the folder contains ONLY files (ie. no subfolders). If that is true, this would work:

```
if (isset($_GET['dir']) && !empty($_GET['dir']))
{
    $checkifhasfiles = array_diff(scandir($_GET['dir']), array(".","..","error_log"));
    $i = 0;

    foreach($checkifhasfiles as $cihf)
    {
        if(is_file($_GET['dir'].'/'.$cihf))
        {
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if ( count($checkifhasfiles) === $i )
    {
        echo "Ok, the folder has files";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, the `break` stops the `foreach` on the first found file, is it correct? If it is so, I want what you've said, echo if the folder contains ONLY files... Let me try

Comment: I've been testing this code, and if a folder has files and subfolders, the script doesn't do echo. What I want is that the script echos in this cases: the folder has files, the folder has files and subfolders. I don't want that it does echo ONLY when the folder is empty or it has only sub-folders, no files.

Comment: A folder can only have 1) subfolders 2) files 3) subfolders & files. If you want to echo out if it has files or files & subfolders, then Jahnux73's answer is the correct one. With his method, if a file is found, the loop will stop, but just before it does, it will perform an echo.

Comment: Yep, I want that 3rd option... It's working :) However, thanks too Marcel!

Answer (score 1):

Easier to check if a folder got children:

```
if(count(glob($_GET['dir']."/*")) { 
  echo "NOT EMPTY"; 
}
```

Comment: Let me try to make an example. I have a web file manager. And I've a function to make a zip from the folder where the user is. What I want is that the button to create a zip appears only when the folder has files in it. If it is empty or it only has sub folders, I want that the button is hidden... So I think children won't work in this case